# How to use the same constructor argument as a class parameter in order to save memory

Tags: c++, constructor

I am currently working in an embedded system that has an extremely low amount of available memory (2 kB!). So, I need to save as much memory as possible. And I need to pass as Struct as argument to the constructor and then work with this struct inside my class. The traditional way that I normally do that is as follows:

```
Class_name::Constructor(Data_type &passed_as_reference)
{
    Data_type newInstance = passed_as_reference;
}

Class_name::AMethod()
{
    third_party_method(this_argument_cannot_be_a_pointer)
}
```

I would know how to do that if only had to work in the same method (as it was passed as reference), but I have to work with it outside of the constructor.

As you can see, I had to create another instance "newInstance" of the struct "Data_type" to work with it in another methods, as in "AMethod()". However, in order to save memory, I was wondering, how can I refer to the same struct in another classes with create a new local instance for the class?

A final constraint: Inside the class, I have to use a third party method that don't allow me to pass a pointer (But I am allowed to pass the whole struct).

Thank you for your time =)!

For sake of clarity, the method bellow is the third party method (the actual method that I am working with) used to store data in persistent memory. Notice that I need to pass the whole data (in my case a struct) as argument.

EEPROM.put(MemoryAddress, data)

Comment: If you have a pointer, you can "pass the whole struct" by dereferencing the pointer (`*ptr`).

Comment: The example you provided doesn't help clarify the question. There is nothing that indicates how you intend to communicate the constructor's argument to `third_party_method`.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case I cannot pass a pointer to the third party method =/

Comment: You don't have to pass the pointer. A dereferenced pointer is in every way the same as the original object.

Comment: I just edited the description!

Comment: It's not clear to me that you fully understand what a pointer is or does. The only possible interpretation for a function not supporting pointers is that the type it expects is not a pointer. And that concern is solved by dereferencing the pointer. Your requirement that the function doesn't work with pointers can't exist in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a member of reference type, so that you don't have to make any copies:

```
class Class_name {
  Data_type &newInstance; // this refers to the parameter passed to the constructor
public:
  
  Class_name(Data_type &passed_as_reference) : newInstance(passed_as_reference) {}

  AMethod() {
    third_party_method(newInstance);
  }
};
```

Comment: This is functionally the same as a pointer member, but with extra restrictions.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux True, but it addresses the OP's question. If the restrictions don't work for the OP, I'll update the solution.

Comment: My concern is OP doesn't fully understand their own requirements and may use this solution without understanding that using a pointer member in the first place is almost certainly going to be better for them. If this solution works for their situation, so would a pointer data member.

Comment: @cigien, did you think about lifetime of the variable passed in the constructor?

Comment: @reyad This lifetime concern seems to be implied by the question. My understanding is that they want to work directly on an instance that lives outside of the `class`.

Comment: @reyad No, but if the lifetime of the argument is not sufficient, then there is no option but to incur a copy.

Comment: @cigien, what do you think about passing pointer...it could solve it...can you take a look at my answer pls...

Comment: @reyad Whether the argument is referred to by pointer or by reference has zero bearing on lifetime concerns. Pointers and references have the exact same behavior regarding the lifetime of their referred object.